# UINavigationController: Duplicate controller at position in stack

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` that gets a few views pushed onto the stack.  Once I am a few levels in, I need to call up a `modal view` that is a copy of the `UINavigationController` and is at the same level in as the calling navigation controller.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think so. We might be able to suggest another solution, if you go into details what you are striving to accomplish.

Comment: I want to move rows from the TableView that is in my navigation controller. When I invoke the new modal, I am in "move mode".  This is where I want a new controller to come up with the same position in the stack, so I can choose a location to move those rows.

Comment: I take it you only have one UINavigationController, right? Or are you creating two separate navcon stacks? The views in a navcon stack should just be UIViewController subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You should not interact with the tableView directly if it is not currently visible. (i.e. when another ViewController is on top of the stack)

A preferable solution to the problem you described in the comments is to modify the datasource and reload the tableView as soon as it is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

To push a *new navigation stack* modally, create a new navigation controller and populate its stack (`setViewControllers:`) with the views you want. You *could* use the same VC instances in this new stack, but I suggest instead new instances (perhaps of the same classes). The old stack will be hidden so long as this new, modal stack is in place. Dismiss the NavCon to get your old stack back.

If you just want to replace the VC in the current stack, you can pop the current VC (probably not animated!) and then push the new one. The user will be able to navigate through the existing stack using the left button in the nav bar, and navigate forward as you've implemented it.

Calling `UINavigationController:setViewControllers` replaces a navcon's entire stack with one call. This transition can be animated or not at your discretion.

Comment: But when I present a modal view, I am adding a new navigationController.

Comment: If you call `presentViewController`, your new view isn't on the navigation controller stack; the concept of 'same level' doesn't apply. It sounds like you want the existing X stack levels, plus a second set of X stack levels, which seem unusual -- especially to enter the second stack in the middle. Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I am wanting a second navigation stack. Look at the Apple Mail app, and look at what they do when you want to move an email message.  It shows a modal with a new stack.  This is the sort of thing I want to do.

Comment: just reworked this answer a bit in response to your clarification.

Comment: Ok, but how do I duplicate the objects of an entire stack?

Comment: `for (eachitem on oldstack) newstack->pushItem( eachitem->clone() );`, or the equivalent. There's no built-in way to do this. Whether the same instances will work for you or not depends on how you implement them, but beware that changes made in the modal stack will then be reflected in the old stack. If you want to clone the objects, you'll have to figure out some way to do that yourself. Something like `[[[oldinstance class] alloc] init]` might work, but you're also going to want some state in there, too... This might be appropriate as a new question by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Bettr to add an button at the leftnavigationitem in each view and write action for **popto RootView** to remove the stack

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

add back button in viewdidload

```
//To set the back buttin on Navigation bar
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"<--" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backclick:)] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Now implwment action

```
- (IBAction)backclick:(id)sender
{
    // To goback to the main view
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please allow me to summarize the answer with a little code snippet:

```
UIViewController *previousVC = nil;
if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers count] > 1)
    previousVC =
        [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:
        ([self.navigationController.viewControllers count] -2)];
else
    previousVC = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```